# Applications of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that science and specially mathematics are based on the set theory. But, I would like to know some direct applications of set theory for computer science and engineering. For example, is there a direct application for the Russell Paradox to computer science and industry?

Comment: *"science... based on set theory"* - I think scientists would be pretty surprised to hear that...

Comment: We know that in modern mathematics the sets appear in the definition of every mathematical object like topological space, group, ring, a cryptosystem, ... . On the other hand, mathematics in the science has a special position and abstract physics and other abstract branches are based on mathematics. So, we can say that these days science are based on set theory.

Comment: Considering that humans could have invented entirely different rules for set theory without affecting or depending on the physical universe one bit, I completely disagree.

Comment: science, mathematics, physics are from human view and are completely disjoint from the universe. As you say, we can have our science. They are our rules and these rules are based on the set theory.

Comment: The axioms of set theory may be required for the formal verification of software. And for resolving once and for all minor technical issues like whether $0^0$ should be left undefined.

Answer (score 4):

First responding to your claim "science and specially mathematics are based on the set theory":

I agree with Zev.  Today we could pick an entirely different foundation for mathematics and I'm rather certain that physicists, biologists, and chemists won't change their attitude with how they apply mathematics to their work.  You don't need to think of simple things like ordered-pairs, inner product spaces, and integrals in terms of their set-theoretic definitions in order to do mathematics.

This is, in a sense, one of the best thing about mathematics; it would be a rather poor feature of mathematics if changing our foundation at all completely uprooted everything we had done.  What if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ ends up being inconsistent?  will all of mathematics be useless?  Of course not, we'll just change the axioms to avoid the contradiction that was shown to arise, and perhaps the set theorists, logicians, and foundationalists will study what happened in-depth, but more likely than not, none of this will affect what (most) scientists can and can't do rigorously with mathematics.

Now, all that being said, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ does find uses outside of mathematics.  In particular, it gives us an entirely unambiguous language to work with, and for that reason provides a great foundation for talking about such objects as recursive/computable functions and Turing machines. So there are certainly applications directly to (Theoretical) Computer Science, for one.

If one thinks of set theory as the "study of infinity", then it has further applications, particularly in the subjects of analysis and topology.  Making precise what is "infinite" allowed us to understand the idea of convergence of series.  Here we also find results that depend on (usual weaker versions of) the Axiom of Choice, and plenty of arguments, examples, and counterexamples that depend quite heavily on the idea of cardinality.  Heck, the basis of several important counterexamples in topology is the first uncountable ordinal, $\omega_1$.

Comment: This is not true at all. If you prove tomorrow that $\sf PA$ is inconsistent, all the computers are going to stop working. Also gravity was invented by Isaac Newton, so if calculus is inconsistent gravity will fail and things will start floating.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No wonder when Edward Nelson claimed to have proven $\mathsf{PA}$ inconsistent the number $\lfloor e^{e^{10000000000}}\rfloor$ started to fade in and out of existence on my paper. XD

Comment: As Hayden said set theory and its objects like $\omega_1$ have nice applications to the several branch of mathematics. But, what I would like to say again is that every thing in mathematics are based on the concept of set and its axioms and when a paradox like Russell"s paradox was happen we can reform the axioms. However, sets are everywhere and mathematical object are defined by sets.